# Number of functions preserving a partition (double direction)

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a disjoint union of sets $A_i \;(1≤i≤n)$. How many functions $f$ from $X$ into $X$ satisfies the condition:

$a,b$ are in $A_i$ for some $i$ if and only if $f(a),f(b)$ are in $A_j$ for some $j$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the sets involved are all finite. Let $n_k=|A_k|$ for $k\in[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. In order for a function $f:X\to X$ to satisfy the given condition, there must be a permutation $\sigma$ of $[n]$ such that $f[A_k]\subseteq A_{\sigma(k)}$ for each $k\in[n]$. There are $(n_{\sigma(k)})^{n_k}$ functions from $A_k$ to $A_{\sigma(k)}$, so for each permutation $\sigma$ of $[n]$ there are

$$\prod_{k=1}^n(n_{\sigma(k)})^{n_k}$$

functions satisfying the requirement, and the total number of acceptable functions is

$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{k=1}^n(n_{\sigma(k)})^{n_k}\;,$$

where $S_n$ is the set of permutations of $[n]$.

Comment: That is so nice and clear!

Comment: Thank you It same my thinking. But Is it no another formula ? (by not use the permutation).

Comment: @WoracheadSommanee: I don’t at the moment see another approach, but I am still thinking about it. Alternatively, I may be able to simplify the expression in my answer a bit.

Comment: @WoracheadSommanee: If the sets $A_i$ in the disjoint partition of $X$ are of equal size, then the expression becomes much simpler.